# Remove padding around data points in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to Pyplot and I'm trying to plot the Raw wave of an audio file together with its spectrogram. I have written the following code and received the result shown in the screenshot below (code is slightly abbreviated for readability):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))

sample_rate, audio = ...  # rate and wave data loaded with scipy.io.wavfile.read
show_wave(audio, sample_rate, fig)

freqs, times, spec = ... # spectrogram created with scipy.signal.spectrogram
show_spectrogram(freqs, times, spec, fig)

def show_wave(audio, sample_rate, fig):
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    title = ... # some title created dynamically
    ax1.set_title(title)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Audio frames')
    ax1.plot(np.linspace(0, len(audio), len(audio)), audio)
    return ax1

def show_spectrogram(freqs, times, spec, fig):
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
    extent = [times.min(), times.max(), freqs.min(), freqs.max()]
    ax2.imshow(spec.T, aspect='auto', origin='lower', extent=extent)
    ax2.set_yticks(freqs[::16])
    ax2.set_xticks(times[::int(len(times)/10)])
    ax2.set_title(...) # some title created dynamically
    ax2.set_ylabel('Freqs in Hz')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Seconds')
    return ax2, extent
```

I want to display both plots stacked so I can compare the raw wave with its spectrogram. However, the plot created with `ax1.plot(...)` seems to add some padding to the left and the right of the data points (the zero-tick is not at the origin of the axes, data points do not span the whole available area) whereas the plot created with `ax2.imshow` does not do this (plots spans the whole area).

How can I remove the "padding" in `ax1.plot`so that the data points from the raw wave and the spectrogram are vertically aligned and comparable?

[image: Raw wave and spectrogram of audio file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ax1.set_xlim(0, len(audio))` to force the boundaries of the xaxis to go from 0 to `len(audio)` which is what your data actually spans, that will eliminate the "padding" you see.

Comment: Simple but perfect... Just what I was missing. Thank you Julien. I updated the question for the sake of completeness.

Comment: They don't have the same xaxis ticks at all though, would that still work (haven't tried)

Answer (score 0):

*Solution of OP edited out of question:*

As Julien Marrec pointed out below the solution is simple: add the following line in `show_wave` and `show_spectrogram` and it worked perfectly...

```
def show_wave(...)
  ...
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
  ax1.set_xlim(0, len(audio))
  ...

def show_spectrogram(...)
  ...
  ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
  ax2.set_xlim(0, times.max())
  ...
```